# Can I resend pushNotification pop-up to my iPhone App if notifications are disabled and application is live on appstore?

Tags: ios, iphone

Suppose first time user clicked on "Don't Allow" option. I need to send PushNotification to user so Can I resend PushNotification pop-up from server side to my iPhone App?
 please help me.

Comment: You can do checking of notifications permission. You can't update anything on the app side if user didn't allowed notifications, because only way of notifying is token that you get when user allows notifications.

Comment: The way you want to send is possible only if at least once you "Allow" and you get Device token on your server to send push message to that device only.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can resend push notification.For that you have to check condition for push notification enabled or not in your code.

Comment: My app is on app store.I need to send message via PushNotification to user while user clicked on "Don't allow" so first i need to send PushNotification pop-up to allow that.

Comment: @Shital....No then you can't send push notification if they denied permission for push notification.You can only send while they uninstall app and reinstall app

Comment: @ swapnil patel  what can i do something at server side to send message to user.

Comment: @Shital...Sorry dear but you can't send until they allow permission for notification from server side.

Comment: @Shital....if you change your code and set any alert for push notification to allow access to push notification. then release new build of your app then you can send notification.

Answer (score 1):

You can not prompt the default Permission alert for Push Notification 2nd time.

But, you can check if Push Notification is enable or not for your app with this method `isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications` and if disable show your own alert to notify user.

Answer (score 1):

If you "Don't Allow" then app will not request for device token to APNS so your app would not receive Device token from APNS so their would not possible to send Push on device.

1. You could un-install application and re-install and "Allow" same.
2. Need to allow from Setting.

> if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string:
>   UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!) {
>                   UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!, completionHandler: { (success)
>   in
>                       print("Settings opened: (success)") // Prints true
>          })
>        }